# What will cause an infinite switch to blow (other than simply a faulty switch)

Tags: electrical, switch, range

Flat-top electric stove. Infinite switch POP and spark. Breaker tripped. Reset breaker. Everything works except one element.  Replaced infinite switch. Same problem again … technician told me must be that both switches were faulty and has order a third switch … I think the fault must be other than the switch. (The problem happened after doing an oven cleaning for the first time.  It’s a new Frigidaire electric range oven) … any help much appreciated

Comment: Do not know those switches, but a pop and spark is a dead short(hot touching ground/neutral) in the circuit/switch.  Would at least check the rest of the circuit from burner to switch to make sure.  Should be easy to test a new switch for shorts before installing.

Comment: What is an "infinite" switch? Many poles?

Comment: @Solar Mike - its a electromechanical switch which varies the average current through the load with a continuous range of possible settings, i.e. an "infinite" number of possible settings. The current actually only gets turned on or off (2 values), but the timing of the on and off pulses is varied average power delivery.